# как вывести результаты в ассоциативный массив

Tags: php

Пример вывода:

```
 ['name' => 'Andrey',
  'surname' => 'Shevchenko',
  'age' => 35]
```

Исходные данные:

```
$name = array(
    "Nikita",
    "Dima",
    "Alex",
    "Sergey",
    "Vlad",
    "Andrey",
    "Artem",
    "Ivan",
    "Anton",
    "Maxim",
    "Oleg",
    "Roman"
);

$surname = array(
    "Melnyk",
    "Shevchenko",
    "Boyko",
    "Kovalenko",
    "Bondarenko",
    "Tkachenko",
    "Kovalchuk",
    "Kravchenko",
    "Oliynyk",
    "Shevchuk",
    "Polishchuk",
    "Lysenko"
);
```

Мой код:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++){
    $randName = array_rand($name, 1);
    $randSurname = array_rand($surname, 1);
    $age = rand(18, 60);
    // print to array?
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

При условии, что массивы имеют одинаковый размер, [можно сделать так](http://ideone.com/IygQ4d)

```
<?php
$name = ["Nikita", "Dima",];
$surname = ["Melnyk", "Shevchenko",];
$age = [20, 35,];

$keys = ['name', 'surname', 'age'];

$out = array_map(function($a) use ($keys){
    return array_combine($keys, $a);
}, array_map(null, $name, $surname, $age) );

print_r($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, что конкретно вы хотите, но вот таким кодом:

```
$output_array = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    $randName = array_rand($name, 1);
    $randSurname = array_rand($surname, 1);
    $age = rand(18, 60);
    $current_array = ["name" => $randName,
                      "surname" => $randSurname,
                      "age" => $age];
    array_push($output_array, $current_array);
}
print_r($output_array);
```

вы на выходе получаете массив из 30 записей указанного вида:

```
array("name" => $name,
      "surname" => $surname,
      "age" => $age
     )
```